# Querying Google Analytics API for less than one day

Tags: python, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am looking to use the Google Analytics API (v4) to try get around some sampling issues we have. Even when I query for just one day, the data is coming back sampled. Does anyone know how to run a query for less than a day, given the required format is YYYY-MM-DD? At the moment, Premium is not an option for us.

We have roughly 33k sessions in a day and 350k pageviews so I don't think we hit the 500k visits in a day limit. I am able to get unsampled data if I look at today (ie. a day that is not complete) but not for yesterday (ie. a complete 24 hours).

Here is my sample for pulling yesterday's data - which returns sampled data (using api_client batchGet method)

```
sample_request = {
      'viewId': view_id,
      'dateRanges': {'startDate': datetime.strftime(datetime.now() - timedelta(days = 1,'%Y-%m-%d'),
          'endDate': datetime.strftime(datetime.now()- timedelta(days = 1),'%Y-%m-%d')},
      'dimensions': [{'name':'ga:pagePath'},{'name':'ga:previousPagePath'}],
      'metrics': [{'expression': 'ga:pageviews'}],
    'samplingLevel':'Large'
    }
```

I would ideally like to query for less than a day (eg. from 1:00 - 05:00 for example) but would also like to understand why I am getting sampled on this.

Edit: I get sampled with more than one dimension (even standard dimensions)

Comment: You're probably getting sampled because of the custom dimensions that you're querying against. If you try something simple (just path) you'll probably won't be sampled for just a day.

Also, the limit is 10 million HITS a month. Even without counting the event hits, just by pageview, you are roughly about/over that limit in a 30day window.

Comment: What do the `samplesReadCounts` and `samplingSpaceSizes` values look like in your return data? Is `samplingLevel` a required field? (I haven't yet upgraded from the API v3, but the equivalent field is not required there.) Unfortunately there is no way I know of to request less than a day's worth of data.